# Can't find component templateUrl & stylesUrl in Storybook with a custom Angular Library and NPM Link

Tags: angular, storybook, npm-link, angular-storybook

I'm trying to create a new Angular 10 library and a separate Storybook as it's documentation and development view. Everything works as expected when the html and styles are inline in the *.component.ts file. But whenever I try to create a new component with separate html and scss files, Storybook gives an error in the console that it can't find the *.component.html/*.component.scss.

**Steps to reproduce**

Create a new library

```
ng new my-workspace --create-application=false
cd my-workspace
ng generate library my-lib
ng generate component notification --project=my-lib
```

This generates a component with the follow setup:

```
  selector: 'lib-notification',
  templateUrl: './notification.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./notification.component.scss']
})
export class Notification
```

Next thing I did was building the library, cd to the `dist/my-lib` folder and run `npm link`.

I also created another Angular project which will contain the Storybook project, I followed this tutorial to get it started: https://www.learnstorybook.com/intro-to-storybook/angular/en/get-started/

After finishing the tutorial I added the library I built earlier to the storybook project using `npm link my-lib` and created a new stories-file in the `/src/stories` for it. After that I import the component in the stories file like `import { NotificationComponent } from 'my-lib';` and everything seems to be good, because it can find the correct component in the linked npm package.

But whenever I run Storybook `npm run storybook` I get the following errors because it cant find the correct templateUrl and styleUrl:

`GET http://localhost:6006/notification.component.html 404 (Not Found)`

`zone.js:690 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load notification.component.html ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load notification.component.html undefined`

Now I am wondering if it is possible to separate the html/scss/ts files as I prefer this for readability. If this is possible, how can I make sure that the root of the components when running storybook is not ./? Should I add some sort of a webpack configuration or are there other solutions?

If anything is unclear, feel free to ask and I will try to provide the information as good as I can.

Thank you and kind regards,

Wesley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion Storybook is not supporting Ivy features yet.
If you disable Ivy in the build, **projects/lib/tsconfig.lib.json** and **projects/lib/tsconfig.lib.prod.json**, it will work.

**tsconfig.lib.json**

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

Here's the [link](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/11693) to the storybook issue for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was hoping for it to work, but now I know for sure it does not (yet). Cheers!